# Is the sphere with a diameter homotopy equivalent to a surface?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is for a homework problem:

> Take the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ and join the north and south poles with a line segment. Is the resulting space homotopy equivalent to a surface?

Intuitively, I think the answer is no, because I can't think of any way to deform the poles to become locally Euclidean. I've noted that the fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}$ and that the space can be deformed into a sphere with the poles identified, or into a torus with a disc in the middle. But I don't know how to use any of this.

Comment: Do you include possibly non-compact surfaces?

Comment: Additionally, note that the surface must be compact as the given space is compact. Hence things like $\mathbb S^1\times\mathbb R$ are excluded

Comment: @Hagen there certainly exist non compact spaces that are homotopy equivalent to compact spaces.

Comment: It isn't specified whether or not the surface should be compact, so I assume it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call this space $X$.  Since $H_2(X)$ is nontrivial, if $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a surface $\Sigma$, $\Sigma$ must be compact and orientable.  By the classification of compact surfaces, no such surface exists with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the classification of surfaces, you can just use Poincare duality: the cohomology of $X$ does not satisfy Poincare duality.  Indeed, $H^1(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, and by anticommutativity $x^2=0$ if $x\in H^1(X)$ is a generator, so the cup product pairing on $H^1(X)$ cannot be nondegenerate.

For yet another argument, take the double cover $Y$ of $X$ corresponding to the subgroup $2\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $H_2(Y)=\mathbb{Z}^2$, which cannot be $H_2$ of a surface.  But $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to the corresponding double cover of $\Sigma$, which is a surface.